# Github Actions Runner Controller - "controller-manager" secret is deleted when helm upgrade is executed for actions runner controller

Tags: kubernetes, controller, github-actions, action, runner

I'm deploying the action runner controller in the Kubernetes cluster and whenever I run the helm chart upgrade using the below command, during deployment "controller-manager" is deleted, how to avoid the deletion of the "controller-manager" secret

In the helm chart values.yml, the value is already updated as false which will be used to tell the helm to not to  create secret

helm upgrade command

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace arc-dev --wait actions-runner-controller ./actions-runner-controller --values ./actions-runner-controller/values.yaml
```

Below is the log for reference:

```
client.go:684: [debug] Patch Deployment "actions-runner-controller" in namespace arc-dev client.go:417: [debug] Created a new MutatingWebhookConfiguration called "actions-runner-controller-mutating-webhook-configuration" in  client.go:417: [debug] Created a new ValidatingWebhookConfiguration called "actions-runner-controller-validating-webhook-configuration" in  client.go:445: [debug] Deleting Secret "controller-manager" in namespace arc-dev... upgrade.go:396: [debug] waiting for release actions-runner-controller resources (created: 2 updated: 9  deleted: 1) wait.go:48: [debug] beginning wait for 11 resources with timeout of 5m0s
```

Any help is much appreciated in advance